# UIAlertView alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton: disables wrong button on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uialertview

I'm currently working on an app that needs to support iOS6 and iOS7.

I'm creating an alert like this:

```
self.newCategoryAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTitleNewCategory", nil)
                                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTextNewCategory", nil)
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonCancel", nil), nil] autorelease];

self.newCategoryAlertView.cancelButtonIndex = 1;
self.newCategoryAlertView.tag = alertViewTypeNewCategory;
self.newCategoryAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
[[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault];
[self.newCategoryAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;

[self.newCategoryAlertView show];
```

In the delegate I'm implementing the following protocol method

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if(alertView.tag == alertViewTypeNewCategory)
    {
        UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        if (!textField.text || [textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            return NO;
        } else {
            return YES;
        }
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the left button is disabled running on iOS6 (as expected), but when running on iOS7 the right button is disabled.

I checked the values of cancelButtonIndex and firstOtherButtonIndex inside the delegate method and they are the same in iOS7 and iOS6.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong? Or a workaround to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like iOS 7 has changed arranging order for buttons as per indexes.
I have tried your code and added few more buttons to check arranging order.

```
[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTitleNewCategory", nil)
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTextNewCategory", nil)
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonCancel", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"Third Button", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"Fourth Button", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"Fifth Button", nil), nil];
```

For UIAlertView in iOS 7

[image]

First button "ButtonOK" is at the top but second button is at the last position and rest buttons placed ascending order same as previous iOS versions.

So, you can check iOS version using [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] and do

```
   if (iOS 7) {
     self.newCategoryAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTitleNewCategory", nil)
                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTextNewCategory", nil)
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonCancel", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", nil), , nil] autorelease];
  }else{
      self.newCategoryAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTitleNewCategory", nil)
                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"MessageTextNewCategory", nil)
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonOK", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ButtonCancel", nil), nil] autorelease];
  }
```

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted because thats how I'm doing it now. But its not really a explanation or a solution for the problem. It seems like UIAlertView is ignoring firstOtherButtonIndex and always disabling the first button

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Yes, you are right UIAlertView only disabling first button in both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: Almost a joke that we are forced to fix it this way... Even now, more than 2 years later :(

Comment: @andres.cianio cant believe whats going on thr in apple. Nothing is worth mentioning from last 2-3 years ):

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 except when I have to support phones and OSs from prehistoric times (3 years ago that is) ;p